# Enter a Csv-File through a Pop-up Window in R

Tags: r, csv, popupwindow, user-friendly

I have seen that there is the nice option to **enter an input** through a **pop-up window** which has been created in **R**.

Is it possible to write a code that creates a pop-up window (or maybe any other nice interface) where one can **enter a csv file?** (or excel file.) 
Would it also be possible to then get an output as a csv or excel file?

I'm thankful for any idea since I'm not sure what is possible in which language. If you think things would be easier in python - let me know. I just thought to work with data frames is very easy in R.

I already explored a bit the package **svDialogs**

There is for example the function dlgInput() which can take as an input some integer and there are also functions such as dlg_form() etc which do similar things. But I don't find a function that would take a csv file or so as an input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rstudioapi`:

`rstudioapi::selectFile("Select File")` returns the file path of your select file, to open a csv interactively, you can use following code:

```r
read.csv(rstudioapi::selectFile("Select File"))
```

You can read more at: https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioapi/reference/file-dialogs.html